# Dot product between the position vector and velocity vector

Tags: vectors

> Given that the $r(t) \cdot (dr/dt)= 6t^2$ for all $t$ and magnitude of $r(0)=0$, find the magnitude of $r(1)$."

I'm trying to visualize the problem; judging by the form, I suspect that if I integrate both sides this in effect is the same thing as taking a line integral of "one-dimensional" vector field of $r(t)$ for $r(t)$. However, I'm having trouble linking it back to the magnitude of the position vector.

Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE, please don't forget to check [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: $\frac{d}{dt} [ a(t) \cdot b(t) ] = a'(t) \cdot b(t) + a(t) \cdot b'(t)$.
So $\frac{d}{dt} [ r(t) \cdot r(t) ] = 2 r'(t) \cdot r(t) = 12 t^2$.

Integrating this, you can solve for $r(t) \cdot r(t) = |r(t)|^2$ using the initial condtions.